# Задача с одномерным массивом. Язык Си

Tags: c, массивы

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить задачу. Задан массив целых чисел. Определить, сколько раз меняется знак в самой длинной последовательности чисел, не содержащей нули. Язык Си.
Большое спасибо.

```
int main() {
    const int N = 10;
    int mas[N], i;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        printf_s("\tmas[%d] = ", i);
        scanf_s("%d", &mas[i]);
    }
    printf_s("\t");
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        printf_s("%d ", mas[i]);
    printf_s("\n");
    int count = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < N - 1; i++)
        if (mas[i] > 0 && mas[i + 1] < 0 || mas[i] < 0 && mas[i + 1] > 0)
            count++;
    printf_s("\t%d", count);
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Покажите как вы решали эту задачу.

Comment: # include <stdio.h>
# include <conio.h>
# include <locale.h>
int main() {
 const int N = 10;
 int mas[N], i;
 setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
 for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
  printf_s("\tmas[%d] = ", i);
  scanf_s("%d", &mas[i]);
 }
 printf_s("\t");
 for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
  printf_s("%d ", mas[i]);
 printf_s("\n");
 int count = 0;
 for (i = 0; i < N - 1; i++)
  if (mas[i] > 0 && mas[i + 1] < 0 || mas[i] < 0 && mas[i + 1]>0)
   count++;
printf_s("\t%d", count);
_getch();
return 0;
}

Comment: В этом же невозможно разобраться. Просто отредактируйте ваш ответ и вставьте программу как код.

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать.

Comment: Под вашим первым сообщением есть кнопка [edit]. На неё можно нажать, а в открывшемся редакторе вставить ваш код, выделить его и нажать Ctrl-K на клавиатуре или `{}` на панели инструментов.

Comment: Спасибо огромное.

Comment: Вроде так с виду нормально все у вас, вот только условие в if надо бы скобочками разделить: if ((mas[i] > 0 && mas[i + 1] < 0) || (mas[i] < 0 && mas[i + 1] > 0)). Что там за проблема была с вашим кодом?

Comment: Нужно массив разделить на последовательности чисел, в которые не будет входит ноль. Среди этих последовательностей найти самую длинную и в ней подсчитать количество раз изменений знака. То есть, к примеру, есть массив, состоящий из чисел {-1, 2, 3, 0, 6, -7, 8, 10, 0, 1},  тогда в этом массиве рассматривать три последовательности {-1, 2, 3}, {6, -7, 8, 10}, {1}. Так как самой длинной последовательностью будет  {6, -7, 8, 10},  то в ней  найти количество раз изменения знаков, в этом примере - 2 раза. Я не понимаю, как разбить массив на последовательности, в которых нет нулей. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
...

int maxCount = 0;
int maxLength = 0;
int count = 0;
int length = 0;
for (i = 0; i < N - 1; i++) 
{
    if (mas[i] == 0)
    {
      if (length > maxLength) 
      {
         maxLength = length;
         maxCount = count;
      }
      length = 0;
      count = 0;
    }
    else
    {
      length++;
    }
    if ((mas[i] > 0 && mas[i + 1] < 0) || (mas[i] < 0 && mas[i + 1] > 0))
        count++;
}
if (length > maxLength) 
{
   maxLength = length;
   maxCount = count;
}
// print maxLength and maxCount
```

https://onlinegdb.com/rk0ofYIjQ

Comment: Может быть есть еще какое-нибудь решение? Потому что у меня ответ при любых комбинациях чисел получается равен нулю.

Comment: @Елена Может быть и есть. Думаю, Вы неаккуратно скопировали к себе код:  https://onlinegdb.com/rk0ofYIjQ

Comment: спасибо Вам огромное, Вы мне очень помогли. Все работает.